# How use Angularjs ng-repeat in spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

i want to create list of input by angularjs ng-repeat in spring mvc. so use this code

```
    <div ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="orders[{{$index}}].name">
            <input type="text" name="orders[{{$index}}].phone">
            <input type="text" name="orders[{{$index}}].mobile">
        </div>
   </div>
```

when i want to retrieve orders in spring controller this exception is catch.

```
   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:
    Invalid property  'orders[]' of bean class Invalid index in property path 'orders[]';
    nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:

```
name="{{order[$index].name}}"//also, notice order not orders
```